# Google Play doesn't call onPurchasesUpdated in Billing Library 1.0

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying restore previous purchased item. As the [reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html#retrieve) say :

> Google Play will call *onPurchasesUpdated* specify this listener
>   setListener() method when creating an instance of the Play Billing
>   Library client.

I created an instance of the Play Billing Library client in onCreate method :

```
  mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build();
    mBillingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

        }

        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
            if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            }
        }

    })
```

And Tried to do some action in onPurchasesUpdated but it didn't work at all (Action like : Toast, Log or update the UI)
Any Help